# How can I direct users to my website for logging in

Tags: c#, .net

I have a desktop app written with dotnet and I want to direct the users to login from my website instead of the app, So when the user clicks login I want to open my website's login form and once the user finishes logging in and return to the desktop app he should be logged in (something like jetbrains rider ide)

So what should I do?

Comment: What you are describing is most likely an oAuth flow.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow